# "set_unexpected" doesn't work in VC2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, exception, exception-specification

I am using VC2010, and write following code to test "set_unexpected" function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

void my_unexpected_handler()
{
    std::cout << "unexpected handler" << std::endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    set_unexpected(my_unexpected_handler);

    throw 1;

    return 0;
}
```

However, "my_unexpected_handler" is never called(the string isn't printed to console, I tried to set breakpoint in my_unexpected_handler, didn't run into).

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks

---

Sorry, I misunderstood the unexpected exception. However, even if I change code to following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

void my_unexpected_handler()
{
    std::cout << "unexpected handler" << std::endl;
}

void func() throw(int)
{
    throw 'h';
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::set_unexpected(my_unexpected_handler);

    func();

    return 0;
}
```

It still doesn't work? That is, "my_unexpected_handler" isn't called.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile. You need to qualify `set_unexpected` with a `std::`. Post the actual code. Also, you are probably looking for `set_terminate` if you're in `main`.

Comment: Pay attention to warnings: `warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)`

Answer (score 3):

You are likely doing nothing wrong. You are using visual studio 2010 and that compiler does not support exception specifications. Well, it will syntax check code using them, but will not check the exceptiontype at runtime.

see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This isn't generally considered a problem as exceptions specifications are generally considered not to be useful, and have in fact been deprecated in then c++11 standard

Answer (score 1):

Since the function throwing the exception has no `throw` specification, the exception is expected. The unexpected exception handler, logically enough, handles only [unexpected exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/set_unexpected/). Nothing makes this exception unexpected.